# How to find a letter in a string in Python

Tags: python, string

Find out if word 'dog' is in a string.

I tried doing this code and i dont know where the error is .

```py
y='dogaway'
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i:i+2]=='dog':
        x=x+1
print(x)
```

I expected output to be 1 but the actual ouput is 0.

Comment: `my_str.find('dog')` will return the index if it is in the `str`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the  `in` membership operator in Python.

```
'dog' in 'dogaway'
```

returns `True`

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output.

Comment: He wants to find out if the word dog is in the string I don't the think 1 is that important

Comment: If what you want is 0 or 1 just do `int('dog' in 'dogaway')`

Comment: @JonathanDyke - From the given information, that is impossible to know why it is the expected output and what they intend to do with it

Comment: @Sayse then how do you know it's not the expected output?

Comment: "I expected output to be 1" is pretty explicit

Comment: It doesn't mean he wants to do anything with that "1", maybe he's just a Python newbie and is trying to do basic operations. The first sentence is pretty explicit as well ("Find out if word 'dog' is in a string.").

Comment: The question is: How to find a letter in a string in Python. Does the provided answer not bring a solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count`.

```
y = 'dogaway'
print(y.count('dog')) # Outputs 1
```

or if you want to fix your code, you are just off by one in your splice:

```
y = 'dogaway'
x = 0
for i in range(len(y) - 3): # Make sure your range accounts for the look ahead
    # In the future add a print to make sure it is doing what you expect:
    # print(y[i:i + 2])
    if y[i:i + 3] == 'dog': # Here you were off by 1
        x = x + 1
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you! your fix really helped me. I do now remind that in slicing y[x:y] , it goes from including x upto y (but not including it).

Comment: @DilshanSandhu If it answered your question don't forget to mark it as an answer. It helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:

```
if 'dog' in y:
    ...
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output.

Comment: As I see your comment is being upvoted, I refer to the same comment on the other answer: You don't know if this is the expected output, as the "1" might only be a flag to check if the containing code is or not working. This *does* what the OP is asking: "Find out if word 'dog' is in a string."